# Measuring time in C

Tags: c, time, matrix, multiplication

I'm trying to measure some activity in C (Matrix multiplying) and noticed that I should do something like this:

```
clock_t start = clock();
sleep(3);
clock_t end = clock();
double elapsed_time = (end - start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Elapsed time: %.2f.\n", elapsed_time);
```

The output is:

```
Elapsed time: 0.00.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try to print just `(end - start)`?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/8583395/318716 might help? Granularity, as Arno points, differs from machine to machine.

Comment: [Rant] The most up-voted answer, with ***11*** upvotes, is irrelevant. But Arno's, or Orwell's (or my) answers (very similar) all have ***zero*** up-votes.

Comment: I agree the OP confused `clock` vs. eg. `time`. But `time` will not help with his measuring 'matrix multiplication.'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`clock` estimates the CPU time used by your program; that's the time the CPU has been busy executing instructions belonging to your program. `sleep` doesn't perform any work, so it takes no noticeable CPU time (even if it takes wallclock time).

If you want to measure wallclock time, use `time`:

```
time_t start = time(NULL);
sleep(3);
printf("%.2f\n", (double)(time(NULL) - start));
```

will print a number close to three.

Comment: MSDN [time()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx): _Return the time as seconds elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970, or -1 in the case of an error._ `sleep(3)` attempts to wait for 3 milliseconds. That little delay may not change the result of `time()` at all.

Comment: @Arno: on POSIX systems, `sleep` takes a number of `second`, not milliseconds.

Comment: Agree! This way you diagnoses this was Linux?

Comment: Why are we casting to a double? Isn't `clock_t` and `time_t` a `long int`?

Answer (score 14):

As a side note, if you want to measure execution time in a more precise manner (milliseconds), [`time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) is not precise enough. You can use [`gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
    long start, end;
    struct timeval timecheck;

    gettimeofday(&timecheck, NULL);
    start = (long)timecheck.tv_sec * 1000 + (long)timecheck.tv_usec / 1000;

    usleep(200000);  // 200ms

    gettimeofday(&timecheck, NULL);
    end = (long)timecheck.tv_sec * 1000 + (long)timecheck.tv_usec / 1000;

    printf("%ld milliseconds elapsed\n", (end - start));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use `time_t start = time(NULL);` and `time_t end = time(NULL);` to get the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [QueryPerformanceFrequency()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as described in Orwells answer or use the [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. The latter has 100 ns granularity but does not increment at that rate. Its increment depends on underlaying hardware and the setting of [multimedia timer resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Keep in mind that the frequency returned by `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` is treated as a constant. However, since it is generated by hardware it has an offset and a drift in time too. Measuring periods in time by using `QueryPerformanceCounter()` will typically be accompanied by errors of many microseconds per second.
I've given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12971720/1504523) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11470617/1504523) answer about similar matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about being tied to Windows, you can try the high resolution timer. It's is a lot more precise than time(), which only has a precision of a single second because it the uses UNIX format.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

__int64 countspersec = 0;
double secpercount = 0.0;
__int64 starttime = 0;
__int64 curtime = 0;

int main() {

    // Get current time, and determine how fast the clock ticks
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&starttime);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&countspersec);
    secpercount = 1.0/(double)countspersec;

    /* calculate something */

    // Standard end-start stuff, account for clock speed
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&curtime);
    std::cout << "Time needed: " << (curtime-starttime)*secpercount << " sec\n";
    return 0;
}
```