# How to make my system support nano seconds precision

Tags: c++, linux, timer, performance-testing

When I run the code from this page [high_precision_timer](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2013/01/27/using-stdchronohigh_resolution_clock-example/), I got to know my system only support microsecond precision.

As per the document,

> cout << chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den << endl;
>
> Note, that there isn’t a guarantee how many the ticks per seconds it
>   has, only that it’s the highest available. Hence, the first thing we
>   do is to get the precision, by printing how many many times a second
>   the clock ticks. My system provides 1000000 ticks per second, which is
>   a microsecond precision.

I am also getting exactly the same value 1000000 ticks per second . That means my system is also support microseconds precision.

Everytime I run any program , I always get value xyz microsecond and xyz000 nanosec . I think the above non-support of my system to nanosec may be the reason.

Is there any way to make my system nanosec supportive ?

Comment: First of all I would check if you get nanosecond precision with [`clock_gettime`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/538609/2802841), if you don't then chances are your system doesn't support nanosecond precision.

Comment: @user2802841 thanks for reply. I am getting nanosecond precision there.The problem is I want to print the current time with nanosecond precision and for that I have used the Boost timer. It only print with microsec precision.

Comment: @user2802841 Is there any other timer which I can use to print current time in nanoseconds precision?.

Comment: Precision maybe, accuracy no.  Obviously, the value will be grossly out-of-date by the time the cout call has completed.  It will take a couple of ns for the light from your display to reach your eyes.

Comment: If you want to operate with nano - ratio must be:
nano std::ratio<1, 1000000000>
micro  std::ratio<1, 1000000>

Comment: @AlexBG how to use this ? any example code to use will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this,
Most processors today operate at a frequency of about 1 to 3 GHz i.e. say 2 * 10^9 Hz.
which means 1 tick every 0.5 nano seconds at the processor level. so i would guess your chances are very very slim.

Edit:
though the documentation is still sparse for this I remember reading that it accesses the RTC of the CPU(not sure), whose frequency is fixed.
Also as an advice i think measuring performance in nano second has little advantage compared to measuring in micro sec ( unless its for medical use ;) ).

and take a look at this question and its answer. I think it can make more sense
[HPET's frequency vs CPU frequency for measuring time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12971110/2689696)

Comment: I use Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 550  @ 3.20GHz
and output of program is:
1000000000
sec = 0:
micro = 543327:
nano = 543327255:

Comment: my system is Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz and output is 1000000 sec, micro = 616303 nanosec = 616303000

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer. I cannot print long message in comment.
I just test your example.
And my system output result was:
chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den = 1000000000.
My system provides 1000000000 ticks per second, which is a nanosecond precision.
Not 1000000 (microseconds).
Your system provides 1000000 ticks per second, which is a microsecond precision.
So, I don't know how to help you. Sorry.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den << endl;
    auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i< 242000000; i++)
        temp+=temp;
    auto end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout <<"sec = "<<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << ":"<<std::endl;
    cout <<"micro = "<<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << ":"<<std::endl;
    cout <<"nano = "<<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << ":"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: to my surprise although my system produces in nanosecond precision with clock_gettime , but not with this chrono, which is much more high precision timer.