# How to make sure nanosleep working in my system in linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, performance-testing, c++-chrono

I have checked that my system is supporting microsec precision [how to make system support nanosec precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503544/how-to-make-my-system-support-nano-seconds-precision) 
Using boost timer I am able to print the current time in microsec precision [Print current time in microsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077299/how-to-print-current-time-with-milliseconds-using-c-c11)

Now when I check whether nanosleep / usleep is working or not, I run this program .

Here is my program1

```
Print current time in microsec 
usleep(1); // sleep for 1 microsec
Print current time in microsec
```

Here is my output

```
01:43:38.799150
01:43:38.799393
```

When I run this program2

```
struct timespec delay;
delay.tv_sec = 0;
delay.tv_nsec = 1000;

Print current time in microsec 
nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
Print current time in microsec
```

I got this output

```
01:48:25.919269
01:48:25.919838
```

I am expecting only 1 microsec difference in current time whereas actually I am getting more than 100 microsec difference. 
What's the reason?

I doubt whether my system properly execute usleep/nanosleep although usleep(1) also call indirectly nanosleep(1000)

I am using g++, linux. Any help or insight will be great and thanks in advance .

Comment: Sleeping in any modern multi-tasking operating system is not precise. You're guaranteed that the sleep will be *at least* the amount of time you requested, but that's it. You also have to take into consideration the time it takes to get and print the timestamps.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your comment. I have checked other option- not printing immediately, instead redirect to a stream and later print it. like std::ostringstream out; out << time_now(); usleep(1); out << time_now();  std::cout<<out.str(); Also I have disabled the other core to get it working in nanosec. BTW is there any way to make my system give nanosec precision atleast sleep for nanosec. If possible please answer my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503544/how-to-make-my-system-support-nano-seconds-precision